# Consume RESTful API regardless of SuccessStatusCode

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Consider the following code segment:

```
//API definition
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/Customer")]
public IActionResult Post(CustomerModel cusomerModel)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest("BadRequest Data Here");
        }
        //...
        return OK("true");
    }
    catch(Exeption ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError("InternalServerError Data Here");
    }
}

public class CustomerModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
}

//API consumer
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/");
var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/Customer", customer).Result;
```

Provided I am the 'API Consumer' is there a way in which I can read there the response regardless of the status code, for example:

```
switch(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode)
{
    case HttpStatusCode.Ok:
        var resultOk = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result; // where Result = "true"
        break;

    case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
        var resultBadRequest = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result; // where Result = "BadRequest Data Here"
        break;

    case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
        var resultInternalServerError = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result; // where Result = "InternalServerError Data Here"
        break;
}
```

Please advise if this is possible.

Comment: If you don't care about StatusCode why do you want to `switch` over it? `httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().Result;` is repeated everywhere. If you want to read content anyway, why don't you do it independently the StatusCode returned?

Comment: your question is not clear... as if you have already written the above code you would know the answer, in the context I'm reading, 'yes' is the answer. which i why i say its not clear what you are asking, as you would be able to see this. also what @RuiFernandes said! ie have the line once and call it responseText or something

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ReadAsAsync method to read the http content, I serialized the http content to return a stream then used a stream reader to stream out my raw content from the http content:

```
var readStream = new StreamReader(httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result, Encoding.UTF8);
switch (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode)
{
    case HttpStatusCode.Ok:
      var resultOk = readStream.ReadToEnd();
       break;

    case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
          var resultBadRequest = readStream.ReadToEnd();
       break;

    case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
          var resultInternalServerError = readStream.ReadToEnd();;
       break;
}
```

It seems as if the ReadAsAsync function can only stream out content if the HttpResponseMessage returns with a StatusCode of OK.